# invitation not accepted user are also registered

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

The feature in my app is a user should first request for invitation and if his invitation is accepted by admin(from admin), a message should be sent that you can signup.

Flow of the feature

User submits the form with his/her email address and mail will be sent saying thank you. Now if admin accepts his/her request, i.e request_accepted will be True now and a mail will be sent saying now you can signup. Finally when user go to signup page and submit the form, it should check if the email that he has filled and submitted during signup has been accepted or not. If accepted, signup is complete with success otherwise display an error stating this email address has not been invited.

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name=_("e-mail Address"))
    request_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('request accepted'))

@receiver(post_save, sender=Invitation)
def send_email_when_invite_is_accepted_by_admin(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    request_approved = instance.request_approved
    if request_approved:
        subject = "Request Approved"
        message = "Hello {0}! Your request has been approved. You can now signup".format(instance.email)
        from_email = None
        to_email = [instance.email]
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True)

def requestInvitation(request):
    form = InviteForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        join = form.save(commit=False)
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        already_join, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        if created:
            already_join.save()
            subject = "Thank you for your request to sign up our community"
            message = "Welcome! We will be in contact with you."
            from_email = None
            to_email = [email]
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True)
            messages.success(request, '{0} has been invited'.format(email))
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)


ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'pages.custom_sign_up_form.CustomSignupForm'
```

custom_signup_form.py

```
from invitation.models import Invitation

class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_email(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        print ('value before adapter', value)
        value = get_adapter().clean_email(value)
        print ('value', value)
        if value and app_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            value = self.validate_unique_email(value)
        try:
            Invitation.objects.get(email=value, request_approved=True)
        except Invitation.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError(errors['Sorry! you are not yet invited'])
        return value

    def signup(self, request, user):
      user.save()
```

The way i am doing allows to signup to non accepted user too.

**UPDATE**

if i put clean_email logic inside signup as

```
def signup(self, request, user):
      print ('request', request, user)
      value = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
      print ('email is', value)
      try:
          Invitation.objects.get(email=value, request_approved=True)
      except:
          raise forms.ValidationError(errors['sorry! You are not yet invited'])
      user.save()
```

i get 'name errors is not defined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Based on the **update** part of your question:

```
raise forms.ValidationError(errors['sorry! You are not yet invited'])
```

There is going quite wrong here. You are saying you  have a [dict](http://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php) with `sorry! You are...` as a `key`, and expecting it to return a value.

This is what you are attempting to access:

```
errors = {
    'sorry! you are not yet invited': None,
}
```

A key like that, with exclamation marks, spaces, etc is invalid.

Note that `error` is not defined in the method (and not anywhere I can see in the class). If you have initialized as a `class` variable, you should access it with `self`.

If you have not yet declared the error dict with a default error message, you should create it as a class variable.

```
class CustomerSignupForm(forms.Form):
    errors = {
        'not_invited': "Sorry! You are not yet invited.",
    }
```

Now in your signup method, you can access the error message:

```
raise forms.ValidationError(
    self.errors['not_invited'],
    code='not_invited'
)
```

---

### Based on the **original** question:

I'm not 100% sure right now what the problem is. But there are a few things you can take a look at and improve.

**Point 1:** Your variable names should explain clearly what it contains. I.e.

```
value = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
```

is a field containing an e-mail string or None. Keep it simple and clear, and keep `email` as variable name. If the value changes in your logic, you can rename it to a new name that clearly explains the contents of the variable. `value` is a too broad name, and is quite confusing.

```
 value = get_adapter().clean_email(value)
```

What is happening here? You have a print after defining value (bad name again), what does it return? What do you expect it to do?

**Point 2:** Keep your validation in the `clean` methods
Your `try` and `except` with the `ValidationError` should be in your form cleaning method. If it does not properly fit in one of the fields that are being cleaned, you should override the `clean` method, run the `super`'s clean method and add the custom method that validates what you want.

**Point 3:** The `signup` method.
I've not seen a place where you call the `signup` method. It is not inherited from `forms.Form`, so it is not yet called as far as I can see.

Note: I'm not going to create any new answers to this topic, I will be updating this 'answer'.

Comment: Thanks for wonderful explanation. It worked but the error is not shown on the page. What might be the reason?

Comment: @pythonLover Not quite sure, but I've updated my answer. There are a few things you can take a look at and improve.

Comment: is not validation process right except naming issue in my clean_email function?

Comment: Well if it does not do what you expect it to do, it's not right. You probably have a view where you handle `CustomSignupForm` with a `form.is_valid` call. Add that source to the question.

Comment: The first update you have posted in your answer works but only the error message is not shown in the frontend saying Sorry! You are not yet invited if the email does not exist or not accepted. But with the second method, i.e extending SignupForm class i am getting an error django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing form class pages.custom_sign_up_form: "cannot import name 'BaseSignupForm'".  Regarding second issue, i think i have to post a new question.

Comment: Well, not sure if you are importing it wrong or posted it wrong in your question. But in your question you are referring to the file `custom_signup_form` (note two underscores) and in the error it is referring to the file `custom_sign_up_form` (three underscores, an additional underscore between `sign` and `up`)

Comment: sorry it was my mistake in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138755/discussion-between-pythonlover-and-nrzonline).